# Insert Once but 2 records inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, insert

```
$query="INSERT INTO tbl_job_seekers (first_name, last_name, email, password, present_address, city)
        VALUES
        ('$FirstName','$LastName','$Email','demo123','$ZipCode','$City' )";


        if(mysqli_query($link, $query)){

            echo "Candidate First Name: $FirstName <br>";
            echo "Candidate Last Name:  $LastName<br>";
            echo "Email: $Email <br>";
            echo "<br><br>Records added successfully.";
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: did you run the query inisde any loop? Your question is unclear BTW

Comment: The code will not reproduce the twice inserterd records.. you sure you didn't submit the same form twice.. by double clicking on the submit button or pressed back and forward in the browser making a second repost..

Comment: Sorry new to the site and mucked up my first post. Raymond thank you for the advice the problem is now fixed.